# How can I get my local dns to resolve to my webserver?

Tags: macos, apache

I'm on 10.11.3 and I'm running Vhosts via httpd.conf and apache checks out. The hosts entries are there and I've pretty much read through every post on stackoverflow about this yet chrome is still failing to resolve the local511 (the site name I have set up).

Any other places to look would be greatly appreciated. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Rebuilt hosts file and I'm closer

Comment: Sounds like more info is needed... depending on how your server is set up you may need to add this to your htaccess file > Options Indexes FollowSymLinks